# REST API - PUT or GET?

Tags: rest, httprequest, api-design

I am designing and building a REST API. I understand the basic concept underlying the different request types. In particular PUT requests are intended for updating data.

I have a number of cases where an API call will modify the database, changing the values of a data object's attributes. However, the new values are not sent by the client but rather are implicit in the specific endpoint invoked. There are arguments needed to select the object to be modified, but not to supply attribute values for that object.

Originally I set these up to be PUT requests. However, I am now wondering whether they should be GET requests instead, because the body does not in fact contain update data.

Which would be recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Just because the body doesn't contain update data doesn't mean it is not an update. Look at it from user's or at least from your API user's point of view. Is it an update from their point of view or retrieval of an object where update is not important from their point of view. If it is an update from user's point of view use PUT.

Answer (score 0):

> Originally I set these up to be PUT requests. However, I am now wondering whether they should be GET requests instead, because the body does not in fact contain update data.

If the semantics of the request are a *change* to the representation(s) of a resource on the server, then GET is inappropriate.

If the payload/entity enclosed in the request is not a candidate representation of the target resource ("make your representation look like this one right here"), then PUT is inappropriate.

"Update yourself however you see fit, here is some information that will help" will normally use POST.

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of "this action isn’t worth standardizing." -- [Roy Fielding, 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

POST is the general solution for requests that are intended to modify resource state; PUT (and PATCH) are specializations with narrower semantics (specifically, remote authoring).